# How does '=' operator works in angular directive isolated scope with 'true' and 'false' values?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I had some code in angular v1.2 that worked.

```
<some-directive isFull="false"></some-directive>

.directive('someDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            isFull: '@'
        },
        template: '<h1 ng-if="isFull">Test Template</h1>'
    };
}])
```

isFull was set to falsy js value in template.

After migrating to angular v1.4 this logic breaks because as I see 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bdfc9c02d021e08babfbc966a007c71b4946d69d
false is interpreted as a string and now it is a true js value.

So I changed

```
scope: {
    isFull: '='
},
```

and this does the trick. But according to the doc, with '=' we do a binding to the parent scope.

Can someone please explain how '=' works with 'true' and 'false' boolean values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is two-way binding, it is usually used with a variable:

```
<some-directive is-full="myVar"></some-directive>

.directive('someDirective', [function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            isFull: '='
        }
    };
}]);
```

This means that when you change `myVar` in the parent scope, the value of `isFull` will change in the directive to the value of `myVar`. And viceversa, if you change the value of `isFull` in the directive, it will get propagated to `myVar`.

Your case is a bit special because you don't have two variables but you have an angular expression which will get evaluated first. Then it will work exactly the same.

You could actually use the new one-time binding `is-full=":: false"` because this value won't ever change.

There is nothing special about booleans here.

Comment: thanks for a clarification! By the way are there any better ways to send boolean values to a directive?

Comment: @yuyokk seems from the notes in the changelog that if you just left value empty would work for `false` ... `true` should evaluate ok

Answer (score 1):

I think [the docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object) may explain it better than I can:

> - `@` or `@attr` - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given `<widget my-attr="hello {{name}}">` and widget definition of `scope: { localName:'@myAttr' }`, then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated value of `hello {{name}}`. As the name attribute changes so will the `localName` property on the widget scope. The `name` is read from the parent scope (not component scope).
> - `=` or `=attr` - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the `attr` attribute. If no `attr` name is specified then the attribute `name` is assumed to be the same as the local `name`. Given `<widget my-attr="parentModel">` and widget definition of `scope: { localModel:'=myAttr' }`, then widget scope property `localModel` will reflect the value of `parentModel` on the parent scope. Any changes to `parentModel` will be reflected in `localModel` and any changes in `localModel` will reflect in `parentModel`. If the parent scope property doesn't exist, it will throw a `NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION` exception. You can avoid this behavior using `=?` or `=?attr` in order to flag the property as optional. If you want to shallow watch for changes (i.e. `$watchCollection` instead of `$watch`) you can use `=*` or `=*attr` (`=*?` or `=*?attr` if the property is optional).

Comment: thanks for a reply, but this point is not clear for me 'If the parent scope property doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION'. In my exampe I'm assigning 'false' and this property does not exist on parent scope.

Comment: This exception is only being thrown if no value has been passed but your directive is expecting it. By using `&` you can make it optional.

Comment: By the way your are not passing a string with `isFull="false"`. To do so, you have to pass it like this: `isFull="'false'"`. Then, you could use `@` to access the string in your directive scope.

Comment: this one I get. Thanks! I'm trying to find the best way to send boolean values to a directive.